# Преобразование двоичного кода в символы (Си)

Tags: c

Добрый день!

Имеется код, переводящий двоичный код в символы, однако работает он только если на вход был дан двоичный код одного символа. Как изменить код так, чтобы прога выводила целые слова и предложения? При этом нельзя включать string.h в исходник.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char myChar;
    char in[255];
    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);

    myChar = strtol(in, 0, 2);
    printf("%c\n",  myChar );
}
```

Comment: А вам не кажется, что  пора уже завязывать с однотипными вопросами, и можно было бы начать хоть что-то самостоятельно делать?

Comment: А что подается на вход? Только 0 и 1, или и символы тоже? Символ - это последовательность из 8 бит? Или как?

Comment: Только единицы и нули. 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 на вход, на выход Hello.

Comment: @Arden При ответе на комментарии лучше указывайте в начале ответа, кому отвечаете. Потому что тогда приходит уведомление об ответе, а так я увидел ваш ответ, откровенно говоря, чисто случайно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, как вы написали в комментарии, бинарные представления символов разделены пробелами -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * in = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111";
    for(char * c = in; *c;)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while(*c == '1' || *c == '0')
        {
            value *= 2;
            value += (*c - '0');
            ++c;
        }
        putchar(value);
        while(*c && *c != '0' && *c != '1') ++c;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Все не 0 и не 1 игнорируются.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *in = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111";

void decode_binary(char *s)
{
    int i,b,c;
    for(i=0,b=7,c=0;s[i];i++)
    {
        if((s[i]&~1)!='0')continue;
        c|=(s[i]&1)<<b;
        if(!b)c=putchar(c)&0;
        b--;b&=7;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    decode_binary(in);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: поясню странности :)  `if((s[i]&~1)!='0')continue;` - символы '1' и '0' отличаются только младшим битом. Отсекаем его, и сравниваем с '0'. `c=putchar(c)&0;` - вызываем функцию и обнуляем переменную одним выражением. :)